# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Trying to match a username input from a form to a username stored in my DB.

I get the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in
```

The code:

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?";
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
 $result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
 $users = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Can anyone tell me how to correct this error please?

Comment: Please read up on PDO prepared statements before posting http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements - Plus, make sure you are connecting with PDO and not another and different MySQL API.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't assign the `->execute()` to `$result` immediately. This just returns `true/false` and thus the `Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object` error appears:

```
$result = $stmt->execute([$_POST['username']]);
// ^ true / false
(true/false)->fetch() // no, you can't
```

You should still use the statement object and then use that to `->fetch()` it. From there you should assign the return value of the fetched result.

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: *Si signore.* Now, let's hope they're indeed using PDO to connect with. You know how it is, *eh?* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah, this is most likely, since (i think) this is a follow up question from earlier. (edit) yeah it is, i was the one who answered.

Comment: Yeah, saw it. Ok, so they are indeed connecting with PDO, otherwise they wouldn't have accepted it ;-) However, the former in my comment above and under their question, still applies ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually, whats weird is, its already in the previous answer i gave the simple steps on how to.

Comment: Maybe they're wanting to try something new; a different technique and it's failing.

Comment: Now *this*, is what I call a quality answer. *Long story Ghost*. [Read about it, somewhat here...](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291974/moderator-view-for-user-flags-needs-an-update). In regards to your "competition" below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- wow, im baffled that answer below was indeed upvoted, but yeah this kind of answer is a trend, especially on our tag. _try this, like this one?, etc.._

Comment: I'm even more baffled as to why you've gotten a downvote for yours. Maliciously done, I'm sure. It seems like there is indeed a trend going on, where people actually support low quality answers. They're the same ones who also give out the same; I've confirmed that. The ones who know what the real score is, were the ones who agreed with me. I know who I can trust ;-) *Cheers buddy, I hope all's well with you.*

Comment: Oh, and if you've seen that meta link I've left above, have a look at the comments I've left and the responses I've gotten from them. Giving my head a real serious shake.

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh i didn't notice that lol :D i did got one. yeah i've read what happened, when i was active at VLQ, for me this was already a delete and downvote. you got ripped off by the robo reviewers

Comment: Hahaha, yeah you could say that; *what a rip!* I want my money back lol